# React Native Navigation stack screen mix up

Tags: react-native, graphql, apollo-client, asyncstorage

There's some logic issue with my stack when I'm trying to login and logout. I'm currently storing a token using AsyncStorage, however, it seems to be a problem of going into another navigation stack and I'm not quite understanding it. I have verified that the token is showing up as intended and being wiped out as the login/logout action gets triggered.

Main Nav Stack:

```
 <NavigationContainer>
      <RootStack.Navigator>
        {
          token !== null ?
            (
              <>
                <RootStack.Screen name="tabnav" component={BottomTabNavigator} options={{ headerShown: false }} />
                <RootStack.Screen name="create-profile" component={CreateProfile} options={{ headerShown: true }} />
                <RootStack.Screen name="profile" component={Profile} options={{ headerShown: true }} />
              </>
            ) :
            (
              <>
                <RootStack.Screen name="test" component={UnauthenticatedRoutes} />
              </>
            )
        }
      </RootStack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer >
```

Tab Nav

```
const BottomTabNavigator = () => {
  const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator()
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator
      screenOptions={{
        headerShown: true,
        headerStyle: { backgroundColor: '#FB5B5A' },
        headerTintColor: 'white',
        headerTitle: () => (
          <Image
            resizeMode='center'
            style={{
              width: 20, height: 20, backgroundColor: '#FB5B5A'
            }}
            source={require('../assets/ios/rocket-lunch.png')}
          />
        ),
        tabBarActiveTintColor: '#FFF',
        tabBarActiveBackgroundColor: '#FB5B5A'
      }}>
      <Tab.Screen name="Dashboard" component={Dashboard} options={{
        tabBarIcon: ({ }) => (
          <Icon name="mobile-phone" size={30} />
        )
      }} />
      <Tab.Screen name="Settings" component={Settings} options={{
        tabBarIcon: ({ }) => (
          <Icon name="gear" size={30} />
        )
      }} />
    </Tab.Navigator>)
```

Login which uses the navigation object to re-route

```
const Login = () => {
  const [email, onEmailChange] = useState('')
  const [password, onPasswordChange] = useState('')
  const navigation = useNavigation()
  const [login] = useMutation(LOGIN_MUTATION, {
    variables: {
      input: {
        email,
        password,
      }
    },
    onCompleted: async (newData) => {
      try {
        await AsyncStorage.setItem("token", newData.login.token)
        await AsyncStorage.setItem("email", newData.login.email)
        navigation.navigate('tabnav')
      } catch (e) {
        console.error(e)
      }
    }
  })
```

Logout which uses the navigation object to re-route

```
case 'Logout': {
      logoutUser()
      navigation.navigate('login')
      AsyncStorage.clear()
      break
    }
```

I get complaints of "The action 'NAVIGATE' with payload {"name":"tabnav"} was not handled by any navigator, also getting it for the logout case function as well. Is this a timing issue?

Comment: Updating AsyncStorage won't trigger update of states in react-native. You will need a **global state management library** (Redex / Context) to handle this kind of login flow. See [react-navigation doc](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/auth-flow).

Comment: @kiuQ hmm... i thought apollo client had reactive variables where it could trigger state change, I was hoping to avoid using context, but I guess I'm not using it correctly or I'm not understanding something about it

Comment: Sorry I missed your `apollo-client` tag. The main reason for the issue is that token is not updated after the login flow. Please update your question with code in Main Nav Stack where you initialize `token`.

Answer (score 0):

Not a timing issue. When you are not logged in your navigator doesn't "see" the `tabnav` route - it's excluded from your navigator by the ternary `token !== null ?`. The opposite is true when you're logged in - you can't see the unauthenticated routes. Therefore you can't switch from one to the other.